# Copy DB file From Flex AIR bindebug Folder To Any Folder Programatically

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a db file Resided in Flex Air Bindebug Folder,Here i want to Move/save this db File at another location let say In mydocument/or any Folder, I am not able to do it's programatically..Please help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *mydbfile.db* is the file in your Application Directory:

```
var fileToCopyFrom:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("mydbfile.db");
var fileToCopyTo:File = File.documentsDirectory("Copy of mydbfile.db");
fileToCopyFrom.copyTo(fileToCopyTo as FileReference);
```

This would copy the file to your Documents directory.  These are all basic functions weill documented in the AS3 Reference for [flash.filesystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are your trying to do this via actionscript or in FlashBuilder/Eclipse? 
If your trying to move around in The IDE then use ANT.